# background image in bootstrap 4 column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, background-image

On my page:

```
<div id="cont" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="sidebarcont" class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="sidebar"  class="position-fixed">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main" class="col-sm-9">
            <div id="first_row">   
            </div>
            <div id="second_row">
            </div>
            <div id="first_row">
            </div>
            <div id="second_row">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#sidebar {
      background-image: url('../Media/cos.png'),url('../Media/ant.jpg');
      background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
      background-size:contain;
      background-position:top;
      height:auto;
      }
#sidebarcont {
      width:100%;
      }
```

I would like the background image to be placed on top of the sidebar, fill the whole width of it (`background-size: contain`) and be fixed. What I have achieved is the sidebar is placed at the top but it is a size: `70px/30px`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `background-size: 100%`, which is 100% width and automatic height. It will stretch the Image to be as wide as your sidebar and keep the aspect ratio.

```css
.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/w3css.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) for a more detailed explanation.

There is also a syntax error in your CSS: leave out the comma in `background-repeat`.